# How to verify if nginx is running or not?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, mono

After [running an ASP.NET vNext project](http://xameeramir.github.io/asp-net-5-ubuntu-linux/) on my local machine I was trying to figure out how I can run it on [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/) as it looks to be a [recommended choice](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/servers.html#choosing-a-server)

Following [jsinh's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/376196/jsinh) [blog](http://blog.jsinh.in/hosting-asp-net-5-web-application-on-linux/), I installed it using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nginx -y
```

I was trying to understand whether it is working or not by using:

```
ifconfig eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2}'
```

After running

```
sudo service nginx start
sudo service nginx stop
```

However, the output is always the same:

[image: Nginx status]

> How to verify if nginx is running or not?

Comment: Nginx has nothing to do with `ifconfig`. Why not to use `service nginx status`?

Answer (score 243, accepted):

Looking at the requirement you have, the below command shall [help](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoTjg.png):

```
service nginx status
```

Comment: And what if `service` isn't available?

Comment: If service is not available, then can use this: sudo /etc/init.d/nginx status

Answer (score 38):

You could use `lsof` to see what application is listening on port 80:

```
sudo lsof -i TCP:80
```

Comment: sudo lsof -i was it for me

Comment: @Sizzling Could it be listening on a different port or not running?

Answer (score 26):

This is probably system-dependent, but this is the simplest way I've found.

```
if [ -e /var/run/nginx.pid ]; then echo "nginx is running"; fi
```

That's the best solution for scripting.

Comment: Doesn't this fail if nginx has died abruptly?

Comment: @Mehrdad it surely does, there is absolutely no guarantee that something will clean up this pid file, so this "solution" is definetely unreliable.

Answer (score 21):

If you are on mac machine and had installed nginx using

```
brew install nginx
```

then

```
brew services list
```

is the command for you. This will return a list of services installed via brew and their corresponding status.

[image]

Answer (score 17):

The modern (`systemctl`) way of doing it:

```
systemctl is-active nginx
```

You can use the exit value in your shell scripts as follows:

```
systemctl -q is-active nginx && echo "It is active, do something"
```

Answer (score 15):

`service nginx status` will work on a non-systemd based version.

On systemd based versions such as Ubuntu Linux 16.04 LTS and above, make use of the command below;

```sh
systemctl status nginx
```

Answer (score 11):

**For Mac users**

I found out one more way: You can check if  `/usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid` exists. If it is - nginx is running. Useful way for scripting.

Example:

```
if [ -f /usr/local/var/run/nginx.pid ]; then
   echo "Nginx is running"

fi
```

Answer (score 4):

None of the above answers worked for me so let me share my experience. I am running nginx in a docker container that has a port mapping (hostPort:containerPort) - 80:80
The above answers are giving me strange console output. Only the good old 'nmap' is working flawlessly even catching the nginx version. The command working for me is:

```
 nmap -sV localhost -p 80
```

We are doing nmap using the -ServiceVersion switch on the localhost and port: 80. It works great for me.

Answer (score 4):

Can also use the following code to check the nginx status:

```
   sudo /etc/init.d/nginx status
```

Answer (score 4):

The other way to see it in windows command line :

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq nginx.exe"
```

> INFO: No tasks are running which match the specified criteria.

if there is a running nginx you will see them

Answer (score 1):

Not sure which guide you are following, but if you check out this page,

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts

It uses another command

```
ip addr show eth0 | grep inet | awk '{ print $2; }' | sed 's/\/.*$//'
```

and also indicates what result is expected.

Comment: @student that post is too old for a moving target such as ASP.NET Core, and it misses so many details.

Comment: Fine, at least it gives me a starting point. If you can show any newer alternative?

Answer (score 0):

Running the `sudo nginx` again gives you the following error [image: Error Image] This indicates that the nginx is running.

or the simple thing you can do is, check if the system that depends on nginx to run like the webapp you might be running, is it working when you hit that particular port